# Differentiate between failed(no network) and cancelled request in ajax error(HTTP status code 0)

Tags: javascript, jquery, http-status-code-301, general-network-error

I am using [Jquery ajaxError](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/) to catch all ajax errors. I am having problem with **http status code 0**. This code is returned when the request fails(no network), or if user refreshes page(or clicks on other tab). I want to differentiate between both. Is there any way to do so?

Comment: Is there a difference in the statusError text field?

Comment: No, it is "error"and field is statusText

Answer (score 2):

I think there is not a straightforward solution but there is a workaround.
On **http status code 0** you can check...

`if(navigator.onLine)`

which will return whether there is some network connected or not.